# Adjective describing someone who is in constant communication with someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm searching for a good synonym for *communicative*, but with an emphasis on being in constant communication over time, not merely the "amount" of communication (so *talkative* and such don't work). A short phrase will work as well.

Example context:

> Unlike our inferior competitors, we are great because we are **communicative** (e.g. *we constantly stay in touch with you*).

Comment: Is it 'connected'?

Comment: @WS2, not quite. I may be nitpicking, but `connected` implies more of an uninterrupted stream of exchange than I want to convey. What I'm trying to say is, "Hey, we are always in touch with you when we (either of us) *need* to communicate."

Comment: I would say 'Sam and I are in regular contact'.

Comment: `connected` can also have *social media* connotations that could imply an intermittent form of communication that could come across as opposite to what you desire (unless you clarify)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular instance I like **at [one's|your] disposal**.  You could also say that you are **a [call|click] away**.

Comment: I like "at your disposal" because it has the closest meaning without alluding to other concepts, and is also succinct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are really looking for *accessible, approachable, available* or *responsive*.

These, of course, are about being communicative *when asked*. If you are very communicative *proactively*, then I'd say you shouldn't be exactly advertising that, because it sounds like you'll be spamming me, or forcing your staying-in-touch with me upon me in other ways. I for one will then very much consider your "inferior" competitors who surely won't refuse answering a question or two of mine, either, but won't keep pestering me with their "just wanted to check back with you"s, "was wondering if everything's alright"s, and "our previous offer has expired, here's an update for your convenience"s.

Comment: Thanks for great suggestions. The context was of an advertising copy where a distinction of being "always in touch" was crucial. The industry for whom the message was intended is known to have companies that charge fees up-front, but have to be hounded by clients for results, so there was no concern of appearing too "spammy" in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Think about ***attentive and transparent***.

The consistently-high level of communication you're describing is *relative to a service rendered*.  Thus, make the words you seek to be contextual to that.  it would have helped to call-out this more explicitly in the question's body.

Staying in constant contact in a service relationship is often regarded as being *Attentive*.  *Transparency* reinforces this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **[linked](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/link?q=linked#link__13)** (or **linked up** or **linked with**)

> make, form, or suggest a connection with or between:
>
> (with object):
>
> *rumors that linked his name with Judith*
>
> *foreign and domestic policy are linked*
>
> (no object):
>
> *she was linked up with an artistic group*
>
> connect or join physically:
>
> (with object):
>
> *a network of routes linking towns and villages*
>
> *the cows are linked up to milking machines*
>
> (no object):
>
> *three different groups, each linking with the other*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider "[tune in [to]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tune%20in)."

> [Because we are tuned in to people and their needs, we subconsciously understand the kind of customers we are serving and what they want.](http://monkeymediasoftware.com/catering-customer-types/)

Also, consider "be in tune [with]," "stay tuned [in to/with]," "[be ready,willing, and able [for]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ready,+willing,+and+able)," and "ready and raring (to help)."

> [We are quick, mobile, up to date, and in tune with our clients and their needs.](http://www.americanlegal.us/services)
>
> [Whether you're looking to completely overhaul your website or add something new to your existing assets, our team is ready and raring to help.](http://dabrianmarketing.com/services/branding-design/web-design/)